# SQL Insert Function (Insert incremental value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to add incremental value on insert function. I have tried the following code but is not working. I want to increment `COLUMN1` by 1 each time.`COLUMN1` is not a key column.

```
@var=0;
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) 
       SELECT @var++,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8 
       FROM TABLE_B;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate sequential value for `COLUMN1`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) 
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 1,
    COLUMN6,
    COLUMN7,
    COLUMN8 
FROM TABLE_B;
```

Comment: But I want a unique value! What happen when you insert for second time?

Comment: Then this will not work. Use `IDENTITY` column instead.

Comment: Or replace `-1` with  `+ (SELECT MAX(COLUMN1) FROM TABLE_B)`. But this could have a problem for concurrent queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make the column as `IDENTITY` column. If it is an existing column then you can add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE (TABLE_A) ADD NewColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)

ALTER TABLE (TABLE_A) DROP COLUMN COLUMN1

sp_rename 'TABLE_A.NewColumn', 'COLUMN1', 'COLUMN'
```

and then simply do like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) 
SELECT
    COLUMN6,
    COLUMN7,
    COLUMN8 
FROM TABLE_B;
```

So now you don't have to provide the `COLUMN1` while doing insert. It will be populated automatically whenever a new row is inserted into the table and it would be incremental by 1.

Comment: in SQL Server 2012 is not recognized sp_rename function

Comment: @user2242558:- You have tagged your question as SQL Server 2008. And sp_rename works in SQL Server 2012 also, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188351(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Added 2008 by mistake! I am sorry about that!

Comment: @user2242558:- As I have linked, it works in SQL Server 2012 as well.

Comment: Tried and not working! It give always COLUMN1=1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `row_number()` function for this. Add the `row_number` to the variable.

```
@var=0;
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) 
       SELECT @var + row_number (),COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8 
       FROM TABLE_B;
```

Initialise your variable as your desired start number. Apologies if it's short I'm posting from my mobile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please. add an example about your correct answer